как сделать символьную ссылку на существующий каталог
У меня имеются две папки, в которых находятся каталоги и файлы
 
Данные папки частично копируют структуру каталогов друг друга. Мне необходимо создать символьную ссылку папки №2 в папку №1, чтобы данные папки объединились, и когда я вношу изменения в папке №2 то изменения происходили бы и в папке №1

mklink/j subdir2 subdir1
